# ckeditor getting cursor from body

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, internet-explorer-9

I am using the CKEditor in a JSP/Javascript project in Internet Explorer and need to get the location of the cursor from the editor.
I have found code that would work if it were a text area but its not a text area. The area where the text is enterred for ckeditor is a body with class ="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders".

```
function caret(node) {
    if(node.selectStart)
        return node.selection.start();
    else if(!document.selection)
        return 0;

    var c = "\001";
    var sel =document.selection.createRange();
    var dul =sel.duplicate();
    var len =0;

    dul.moveToElementText(node);
    sel.text = c;
    len = (dul.text.indexof(c));
    sel.moveStart('character',-1);
    set.text = "";

    return len;
}
```

The above code works if I don't make my textarea a ckeditor instance. When I make it a CKEditor instance, Using alerts I have been able to trace the code and find that "dul.moveToElementText(node)" is the line where the code crashes. I believe this it is because that code only works for a text area, so I was hoping someone would know of similar code that will work for a body element.

Thanks

Comment: CKEditor documentation: [`editor.getSelection()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-getSelection)

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I have tried that. That along with getNative works if I am selecting text, like a whole word. Because I need to create hyperlinks to images and documents on our system based on user selections I need the character number where the cursor is located. That way I can pop the hyperlink in that exact location. Yes I know ckeditor has their own link creator, but my users won't be able to handle that and I have extra data I need to get from their selections.

Comment: So you are not building a custom plugin, but building your own without using CKEDITOR? What do you mean character position and pop up. Pop up the hyperlink where? When the user is using the page? Why are you not just using location info when they click the link??

Comment: Because my users need to choose from a set of data not just browse to files I felt that making my own popup to allow them to choose thier images or documents was a good idea.

Comment: Yes you can use CKEDITOR to build your own pop up using their framework...You can also extend the image dialog [what I do in my project] to change the image field.

Comment: The only missing piece right now is the place where the cursor(or caret) is located within the ckeditor when the user clicks the button to open the file selector. I may be able to transition that into a plugin but I still think I will have problems getting that cursor number.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just swap out text with a new element here is the basic idea:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="ed" contenteditable="true">Hello World</div>
<hr/>
<button id="swap">Swap?</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.ed;
document.getElementById("swap").onclick = function(){
    var txt = editor.getSelection().getSelectedText() || "";
    var reversed = txt.split("").reverse().join("");
    var linkHTML = "<a>" + reversed + "</a>";
    var newElem = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( linkHTML, editor.document );
    editor.insertElement( newElem );
};
```

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/VKDCF/

**More info:**

Now if you cause the editor to blur, you will have an issue wince the selection will be lost.

In that case you will need to call lock and unlock

```
editor.getSelection().lock();    //call when you start your dialog
editor.getSelection().unlock();  //call when your dialog is done
```

Ideally you would not be creating a plugin this way, you should create it following the tutorial http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1 or extending it by hijacking the dialog events and overriding functionality.